# MDX Hierarchy (Children, Parent)

Tags: mdx, olap-cube

i have question about MDX code. For example, we have hierarchy: 
**GeoDim**: Country-Region-City.

1.)And now the question is, if i write MDX code like that:
[GeoDim].[City].[Barcelona].Parent.Parent.Children

What will be the result of this MDX code?

2.)And if i write code like that:
[GeoDim].[Region].Members, what will be result of this code?

Thank you for answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Looks valid and should return all the regions.
2. Does not look like valid MDX you usually write `[GeoDim].[Region].[Region].MEMBERS` and it returns the set of regions.

You need to test the different syntax as sometimes you will get the `All` member returned within your set.